# How to check if args[1] is in a range of numbers

Tags: discord.js

I tried the following code, the bot doesn't error but the command replies with the true outcome only, even when the args[1] is out of the range.

This is the code I tried

```
    if(Number(-10) << parseInt(args[1]) << Number(10)) {
        message.channel.send("yes")
    } else {
        message.channel.send("no")
    }
```

I also tried using the `parseInt` function on the values of `10` and `-10`, but same issue, the bot replies with `yes` only

Comment: I'm guessing it is because you're using the bit-shift operators instead of the comparison operators. Try `<` instead of `<<`. Note that as far as I know, Javascript doesn't support `a < b < c` syntax.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Same thing happens, bot still replies with `yes` only

Comment: Try parsing the value into a variable first, and then `if (Number(-10) < value && value < Number(10))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike Python, you cannot do 2 comparisons in the same "block" of code.

The code `1 < 2 < 3` is actually doing `(1 < 2) < 3` which actually works out as `true < 3` and as JS uses false=0, true=1, you are now checking if 1 < 3, not if 2 is.

So, in your case, it will always return true as either false(0) OR true(1) will be less than 10.

Just change it to `-10 < parseInt(args[1]) && parseInt(args[1]) < 10` with an undefined/length check before it.

For example:

```
if (args.length >= 2 && -10 < parseInt(args[1]) && parseInt(args[1]) < 10) {
    message.channel.send("yes");
} else {
    message.channel.send("no");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JS won't throw any error of IndexOutOfRange as other languages like C#, Java.

It'll return `undefined` instead.

Please below snippet for how it may happen.

[image: Snippet]

If your logic is to check a value in between -10 and 10, you have to change a little bit with an `&` operator.

Cheers.